# Can you have an aggregate function within a UDF in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

When I try to use a UDF that has an aggregate function, I get the following error:

```
Aggregate function APPROX_QUANTILES not allowed in templated SQL function call
```

Here's an example function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(x ANY TYPE) AS (
APPROX_QUANTILES(x, 100)[OFFSET(25)]
);
```

Is there any way to include an aggregate function (in my case, `APPROX_QUANTILES`), within a UDF in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below instead

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(x ANY TYPE) AS ((
  SELECT APPROX_QUANTILES(y, 100)[OFFSET(25)]
  FROM UNNEST(x) y
));
```

Comment: When I tried that I got this error: `Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type INT64 Analysis of function`

Comment: obviously, you should pass array to that proc. provide your example of use and i will add proper call example into my answer

Comment: thank you!!! used `ARRAY_AGG` and it worked :)